# Change dropdownlist CSS when clicked or hover?

Tags: jquery, html, events, drop-down-menu, radio-button

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624102/enable-a-currently-disabled-dropdown-list-when-clicking-the-dropdown-list I tried something and I added some grey background to disabled selection.

The problem is that when I click on some selection (which radio button was disabled) the background of the dropdown list remains grey.

How could I turn it back to normal (white) when clicked even if radio button isn't checked?

You can see it live here http://jsbin.com/okuca/

Here is my actual code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test </title>
<style type="text/css">
  label.disabled select { opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50); background-color:#CCC; }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('div.formdiv').bind('click',function() {
      $('label.disabled',this).removeClass('disabled');
      $('input:radio',this).attr('checked',true);
      $('div.formdiv').not(this).find('label').addClass('disabled').find('select').attr('selectedIndex',0);
    }).find('label').addClass('disabled');
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="formdiv">
  <label for="Name">
    <input id="Name" name="radio1" type="radio" />Name:
    <select name="select1">
      <option value="Rose">Rose</option>
      <option value="Lily">Lily</option>
    </select>
    </br>
  </label> 
</div>

<div class="formdiv">
  <label  for="Colours">
  <input id="Colours" name="radio1" type="radio" />Colour: 
  <select name="select2">
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
  </select>
    </label> 
  </br>
 </div> 

<div class="formdiv">  
 <label  for="Sport">
  <input id="Sport" name="radio1" type="radio" />Sport: 
  <select name="select3">
    <option value="Tennis">Tennis</option>
    <option value="Cricket">Cricket</option>
  </select>
  </label> 
  </br>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can edit it here:
http://jsbin.com/okuca/edit

Comment: FYI, your example is working perfectly fine on firefox. When you click on a select box the radio button become enabled.

Comment: @Nadia — The problem is that if you click on the drop-down list for a disabled radio button, the drop-down is still styled as "disabled", even though it becomes selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the click handler isn't being fired until you let go of the mouse button (and the drop-down vanishes), so the `label.disabled select` style is still applied.

There are two ways to fix this.  First, you could add another CSS rule for `:focus`, which overrides the disabled styling:

```
label.disabled select:focus { opacity: 1.0; filter: alpha(opacity=100); background-color:white; }
```

However, this could get you into trouble if your styles get more convoluted.  Instead, I'd recommend changing your click handler to a mousedown handler:

```
$('div.formdiv').bind('mousedown',function() {
```

This causes the handler to fire (and the class to be removed) *before* the drop-down appears.